# Pacemaker continously logging "Changed active directory"

Tags: centos, centos6, cluster, pacemaker

I have a newly installed CentOS 6.6 two-node cluster using Pacemaker. Every 10 seconds `/var/log/pacemaker.log` shows this "Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores/root" message (and nothing else):

```
May 28 11:04:15 [2671] cluster1 crmd:     info: crm_log_init:   Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores/root
May 28 11:04:25 [3087] cluster1 crmd:     info: crm_log_init:   Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores/root
May 28 11:04:35 [3504] cluster1 crmd:     info: crm_log_init:   Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores/root
```

Is this normal? Is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It looks like the message gets triggered by the polling mechanism of [LCMC](http://lcmc.sourceforge.net/), if I close LCMC the message doesn't appear anymore.